# Using set link command in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My data file is shown below

```
x-axis (1/T)    y-axis
6.78E-01    -1.907881356
6.73E-01    -1.828333333
6.69E-01    -1.749849498
6.64E-01    -1.672408638
6.60E-01    -1.595990099
6.56E-01    -1.52057377 
6.51E-01    -1.446140065
6.47E-01    -1.372669903
6.43E-01    -1.300144695
6.39E-01    -1.228546326
6.35E-01    -1.157857143
6.31E-01    -1.088059937
6.27E-01    -1.019137931
6.23E-01    -0.951074766
6.19E-01    -0.883854489
6.15E-01    -0.817461538
6.12E-01    -0.751880734
6.08E-01    -0.687097264
6.04E-01    -0.623096677
```

Gnuplot script is given below

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 6in,5in  
set output "JNM_2020_F2.eps"
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 16"
set xtics nomirror 
set xlabel "10^{3}{/Symbol \264} 1/T (K^{-1})" font "Times-Bold,20"
set ylabel "y" font "Times-Bold,20"
set key outside right top 
set x2tics out scale 1.5 
set link x2 via 1000./x inverse 1000./x
set x2tics 50 
set x2label "Temperature (K)" font "Times-Bold,20"
plot [0.60:0.70] 'Data.dat' u 1:2 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Ref. [7]"
```

Essentially, x-axis plots 1000/T and linked x2-axis plots T (in Kelvin). The script works fine. Now, suppose the x-axis is variable `p` and the linked x2-axis has to be `p+k`, where `k` is a constant, then what should be the `set link` command? In the data file, column 1 is given as 1/T (in Kelvin inverse), so if I have to plot the linked x2-axis as temperature in celsius, then the mapping is from f(x) to 1/f(x) - 273. What should be the `set link` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the x values in 1/K, then you need
`set link x2 via 1./x-273.15 inverse 1./(x+273.15)` to get Celsius.

Consider the following `mydata.dat` file:

```
T [°C]    T [K]    inv. T [1/K]    val 
-15       258.15   0.003873        1.55e
-4        269.15   0.003715        1.39e
0         273.15   0.003660        1.34e
1         274.15   0.003647        1.31e
12        285.15   0.003506        1.18e
14        287.15   0.003482        1.11e
```

from which you use columns 3 and 4, the inverse temperature in 1/K, and some measured quantity val. To plot this, use

```
set xlabel "inverse temperature [1/K]"
set ylabel "some measured quantity"
set x2label "temperature [°C]"
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics 5
set link x2 via 1./x-273.15 inverse 1./(x+273.15)
p "mydata.dat" u 3:4
```

In your case, the x values are not 1/T, but 1000/T, so using your formatting altogether:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 6in,5in
set output "JNM_2020_F2.eps"
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 16"
set xtics nomirror 
set xlabel "10^{3}{/Symbol \264} 1/T (K^{-1})" font "Times-Bold,20"
set ylabel "y" font "Times-Bold,20"
set key outside right top 
set x2tics out scale 1.5 
set link x2 via 1000./x-273.15 inverse 1000./(x+273.15)
set x2tics 50
set x2label "Temperature [°C]" font "Times-Bold,20"
plot [0.60:0.70] 'Data.dat' u 1:2 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Ref. [7]"
```

This produces an output like
[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

As the name says, gnuplot requires the **inverse** function, which you have to solve analytically. You've done it correctly for

```
x2 = 1000 / x → x = 1000 / x2
```

Similarly:

```
x2 = x + k → x = x2 - k
```

Simply write down the mapping function and then solve it for x.